# Copying image with dd results in ext4 filesystem as unknown

Tags: filesystems, dd

I've been trying to make a backup of this raspberry pi SD card and I keep failing. I just needed it a little bit smaller so it would fit on another 32GB SD card that I have. After a lot of failures following tutorials (like pishrink) I shrank my root fs down to around 8GiB which should fit just fine.  Then I copied it over with DD like this:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=small.img bs=1M count=10240
```

and to the target like this

```
dd if=small.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M count=10240
```

Whenever I do this the root partition ends up with an unknown filetype. It is originally ext4, here is the working SD Card in gparted. You can see the root partition is happy as ext4.

[image]

And here is gparted on the second card after I try to write it.  The boot partition is fine but something happened to the ext4 root partition. The PI actually boots up until it tries to load the root partition. This happens no matter how many times I try to copy the image, or even if I try to leave off the size in the dd command. What could I be missing here?

[image]

I should say that I did all of this copying on my ubuntu machine after removing the SD card from the PI.  So the filesystem was not in use on the card when copying it.

I was finally able to get it to boot though by putting the bad SD card into my ubuntu machine and running `fsck -l /dev/mmcblk0p2`. I ctrl-c'd when it started talking to me about garbage.

[image]

And now gparted sees it as ext4 and it boots...  But what the heck :) I don't get why this happened.

Comment: Try again but make sure the partition you are copying is not mounted. It appears to be mounted in your first picture presumably to your Ubuntu machine

Comment: @PonJar okay I just tried this, it takes about half an hour to do a run.  I unmounted, checked with gparted that there were no locks but I got the same results.

Comment: Use `mount` to check if it's mounted or not

Comment: Okay, I tried it again. This time I checked to make sure it was not mounted by running mount.  When it is mounted I see it, after I unmount and run mount they are gone.  Same results though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try copying a filesystem that's in use - at best you'll get a bad copy that falls but at worst you'll get a filesystem that has hidden corruption. Instead, use a different system to copy the SD Card.

Remember that although you now say you use a separate system to perform the copy,

1. The filesystem must still not be mounted (use `mount` to list the set of mounted filesystems - it must not be listed)
2. Make sure you `sync` after writing to the SD Card to ensure everything has completed *before* pulling it to test in the target system

Next time you copy out the filesystem, consider using `cat` instead of `dd`. At best it'll be no slower and it's likely it'll be faster. (The `cat` command must be run as root - use `sudo -s` to get a root shell):

```
cat small.img >/dev/mmcblk0    # Write image
sync                           # Guarantee completion on slow media
```

If you were simply copying a full SD Card you could also use `cat` to copy it completely:

```
cat /dev/mmcblk0 >full.img     # Read image
```

In either case you could replace `cat` with `pv` to get a running progress report. (`pv` also had options to stop processing after a certain amount of data; see `man pv`.)

Comment: Okay I tried this but it ended with pv: write failed: No space left on the device.  This is because the new SD card is slightly smaller than the original. They are both 32GB cards.

Comment: Hah :) The card did work though. I killed pv, and called sync.  And it booted in the Pi

Comment: @confused good point - dd has an upper limit that I forgot to consider. Nevertheless the copy of valid data should have succeeded anyway